# How to install `g++12` on Ubuntu 20.04.6?

Tags: 20.04, c++, g++

How can I install `g++12` on Ubuntu 20.04.6?

I tried a few ways on google but none seems to work.

Comment: What is Ubuntu 20? Update your question with the release you're using. If unsure, try referring to the output of `lsb_release -a` on the command line.

Comment: Do `dpkg -S g++` and `apt-cache search g++`.

Comment: GCC 12 wasn't out yet when Ubuntu 20.04 LTS was released (the current release at that point in time was GCC 9.3). However g++ 12 is available on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and later. You can install newer versions on older Ubuntu releases, but the simplest route might be to upgrade your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been [answered by @Marcus Müller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/720749/322816) in the Unix & Linux question [How to install g++12 on Ubuntu 20.04?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/720734/322816) Essentially, Marcus Müller says that *it may* be possible to install `g++12` on Ubuntu 20.04, but it's very hard to do, so **it is strongly recommended that you use a later version of Ubuntu, such as 22.04, which supports `g++12`**.

I'm quoting the whole answer below:

> If you were considering updating to a more recent long-term supported (LTS) version of Ubuntu, it might be a good time to do it now: Ubuntu 22.04LTS allows you to just install GCC 12's g++ using `apt install g++-12`, done. I predict that unless you have a lot of software depending on obsolete dependency libraries, updating your Ubuntu might be the easiest way to get `g++12`! (You can easily try that out in a `podman` or `docker` container, which I'll not go into here.)
>
> If you're stuck to Ubuntu 20.04, I guess the cleanest and most straightforward way of getting `g++12` will be to try and backport the 22.04 `g++12` package. In that case, you don't have to worry about learning how to build GCC, and how to install a competing g++ that doesn't break all your system by interfering with existing compilers and even worse ABIs. Debian (and Ubuntu as kind-of-downstream of that) have taken the workload of learning that, and you just need to use their tools. Awesome!
>
> Roughly speaking, the procedure to do that is this:
>
> 1. Prepare to build a Debian/Ubuntu package:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt update
>    sudo apt install -y build-essential fakeroot dpkg-dev devscripts cmake debhelper-compat dh-python equivs
>    ```
> 2. Get the package sources. You will need to find the link to the `.dsc` file on the [package page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/g++-12):
>
>    ```
>    mkdir gcc-12
>    cd gcc-12
>    dget -u https://URL/OF/DSC/FILE.dsc
>    ```
> 3. Install the build dependencies from the `.dsc`:
>
>    ```
>    mk-build-deps -i gcc-12*.dsc
>    ```
> 4. Build the packages:
>
>    ```
>    cd gcc-12-somethingsomething
>    dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -d
>    ```
>
> So far for theory. In practice, step 3 will fail – GCC12 depends on tools whose version shipped by Ubuntu 20.04 is simply too old. Especially, the Debian package says you'd need at least `g++11`, `binutils` >= 2.37.
>
> This is really the point where *I* personally say *"If some software that I build needs a bleeding edge C++ compiler, it won't be happy with my Ubuntu 20.04 environment, anyway, and I need to update to a more modern Ubuntu"*. So, again **that's my recommendation; update to Ubuntu 22.04**, and then `apt install g++-12`.
>
> If you want to live with the hassle, you will start to modify the `gcc-12-12.*/debian/control` and `rules.conf`, `rules2` files to depend on just *some* `g++` instead of `g++11`, disable ADA support, be less demanding of `binutils` etc.
>
> However, you can be darn sure that the Debian folks thought about which versions of dependencies to use, and what fixes and backports to include. This is a rocky road. Probably less rocky than a "bare" source build, but it's an easy way to learn way more about GCC than you ever intended, and spend a couple of hours just to start the build.
>
> Honestly, I keep repeating myself, but: if you suddenly find yourself in need of a modern compiler, it's a good time to update to a modern environment. That's way less pain and has way more benefits.